# Position div under parent div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a layout like this (simplified):

```
<div class="row row-1">
  <div class="block">block title 1</div>
  <div class="content">Content of the 1st block</div>
</div>
<div class="row row-2">
  <div class="block">Block title 2</div>
</div>
<div class="row row-3">
  <div class="block">Block title 3</div>
</div>
<div class="row row-4">
  <div class="block">Block title 4</div>
</div>
```

My CSS (responsive design)

```
.row {
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .row {
    width: 32%;
  }
}
```

The first two blocks are displayed next to each other on small screens, 3 blocks are displayed in 1 row for larger screens. The `content` div of the `row-1` div must be displayed under the first row of blocks. the next block(s) is/are positioned under all this.

I tried to use `position:absolute;` on the `content` div, but then it's positioned outside the page flow. The content overlaps the next blocks. Content will be variable, so a fixed height (and a fixed margin-top for the next div) is no option.

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a mock-up of what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `float:left` is what's killing this. Typically as a rule of thumb, you should only use CSS `float` as a very last resort, because it often introduces unwanted interactions with other floated elements.

Set `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: top`. This will cause the blocks to keep their block shape and yet flow like text.

Example at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3agtjro/).

```
.row {
  width: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .row {
    width: 32%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Although Ryan Muller is spot on, you can use flexbox as well.

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/s37cqL0o/4/)

I wrapped everything in one `<section class="flex">`

**Relavent CSS**

```
    .flex { 
       display: flex; 
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .flex { 
       display: flex;
       flex-flow: column wrap; 
     }
   }
```

Note: I changed your media query from `min-width: 768px` to `max-width: 768px` on the assumption that your intention was to accommodate mobile devices.